# Вставьте буквы(,) необходимые в следующих словах

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Вставьте буквы(,) необходимые в следующих словах: *кр...хтеть, недос...гаемые, непост...жимый, флаги разв...ваются, н...в...лировать.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово *буквы* не нуждается в определении, поэтому сам оборот нужно обособить, т. к. смысл не нарушится:

*Вставьте буквы, необходимые в следующих словах: «кр...хтеть, недос...гаемые, непост...жимый, флаги разв...ваются, н...в...лировать»*.

Сравните с:

*Вставьте буквы: «кр...хтеть, недос...гаемые, непост...жимый, флаги разв...ваются, н...в...лировать»*.

Как видите, задание понятно и без оборота — следовательно, определяемое слово не нуждается в определении — следовательно, оборот не необходим — следовательно, обособляется.

Сравните с прошлым вашим примером:

*У нас в деревне нет дома большего, чем мой*;

*У нас в деревне нет дома*.

Согласитесь, смысл совсем другой, а здесь смысл не пошелохнëтся, поэтому оборот обособляем.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно:

*Вставьте **пропущенные буквы** в следующих словах: кр...хтеть, недос...гаемые, непост...жимый, флаги разв...ваются, н...в...лировать.*

Так надо писать. Только так! Иначе ваш учебник не одобрит ФИПИ (Федеральный институт педагогических измерений).

Comment: Nonsense! Complete nonsense! I'm a quiz maker!

Comment: As you wish, sir. This is my opinion. You have an incorrect style. And semantics too. Who says so!

Comment: Letters are necessary. What's that supposed to mean?  Kids, don't miss the letters! Every letter in a word is very important.